# Running Multiple Sql Commands in a Loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I successfully executed the sql code below from an msql editor (phpmyadmin), testing it with one customer (where `Customer No`=1). I need to now run the sql script for all the customers.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `addresses` (`AddressLine1`,`CityID`,`ProvStateCode`,`AddressPostCode`,`CountryIso`) SELECT `Bill To Address`,`Bill To City`,`Bill To Province`,`Bill Code`,`Country` FROM `pdx_customers` where `Customer No`=1;
SELECT @last_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT `Customer No` FROM `pdx_customers` 
INSERT INTO `customer_addresses` (`CustID`,`AddressID`,`AddressTypeID`) Values(1,@last_id,1);
COMMIT;
```

It seems I would need to create a stored procedure ? In a loop, I need to get the `Customer No` dynamically for each row in the `pdx_customers` table, and enter into the Values clause in the insert command, i.e Values(@CustID,@last_id,1). Not sure how I would do this ?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: If MySQL has something like MSSQLs OUTPUT or MERGE then you could do it all in sql, no looping. Worth a look.

Comment: Please look at Cursors in Stored procedure. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really common problem, and I would say that doing a loop in sql is almost never a good idea. Here is another option, which you may or may not consider good as it does introduce a new column. I've used it in some apps I've done, and its made things very simple. Does depend on your use case though so it wont be for everyone.

1) Firstly, add a new column to the address table, call it something that wont be confused by anyone looking at the table like TempInsertId.

2) When writing the new address, include the CustomerId in the TempInsertId column

3) Now you can easily read the AddressId and CustomerId back and write it into the CustomerAddress table

4) If you wish, do a final update to set the TempInsertId back to null.

As I said, not advocating in all cases, but it can be a very simple solution to the problem.

Comment: Worked well,I created a temp column in the address table (CustID),:                                                                                                          
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `addresses` (`CustID`,`AddressLine1`,`CityID`,`ProvStateCode`,`AddressPostCode`,`CountryIso`) SELECT `Customer No`, `Bill To Address`,`Bill To City`,`Bill To Province`,`Bill Code`,`Country` FROM `pdx_customers`;
SELECT  @last_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `customer_addresses` (`CustID`,`AddressID`,`AddressTypeID`) SELECT `CustID`,`AddressID`, @add_type :=1 from `addresses`;
COMMIT;

Comment: Great - If your addresses are always for a single customer then that's perfect. Your original schema allowed for an address to be shared between multiple customers, which is why I used a Temp column name. I gather thats not the case so all good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below statement to create a loop:

```
start transaction;
 while counter < max do
  insert into . . . ;
 set counter=counter+1;
end while;
```